# Locking a Wacom/graphics tablet to one screen and the mouse to another (Dual Monitor Setup)

Tags: multiple-monitors, graphics-tablet, mouse-cursor

Does anyone have a solution to lock input from your graphics tablet to one screen and your mouse to another? It's easy to do it for the Wacom tablet because the software that comes with it allows you to map it to a chosen monitor but restricting the mouse cursor movement so it only affects the mouse input and not the tablet isn't easy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any software that will restrict the mouse to a specific screen I'm afraid. I guess that it would be possible to write something but it might put a fair overhead on the system unless you were to hack the mouse driver. You could possibly even use AutoHotKey to do it but it wouldn't be efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can download Dual monitor tools where you can create a shortcut for "lock cursor onto screen", which you will use once for your mouse on monitor 2, for example.

Also create a shortcut for "move cursor to next screen".

Using the software for your tablet, map the pen to monitor 1. Now your pen will work just on monitor 1, and the mouse will be always be locked on one of the two monitors.

On which one you can change with the shortcut "move cursor to next screen". It will automatically move the cursor from monitor 2 to 1 when you use your tablet, but you will have to use the shortcut for moving the cursor to monitor 2.