# Locking graphics tablet to one screen (dual monitor setup)

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, mouse-cursor, graphics-tablet

I am using an [old "Kanvus Office 54" graphics tablet](https://www.amazon.co.uk/KANVUS-OFFICE-GRAPHICS-WORKING-2540LPI/dp/B0069IMG1I) with a Windows 10 laptop PC and I'm looking to restrict the tablet's output to just one of my two screens (I have a dual monitor setup with my laptop and a separate screen). At the moment, the small 5.5x4 inch graphics tablet screen maps to both of my two monitors, which are side-by-side and so form a very wide area, making it difficult to carry out detailed movements accurately with the tablet (a challenge, given that I'm hoping to use it for handwriting onto documents).

Can anyone offer any ideas of how to **map my graphics tablet to only one screen**, given the tablet's driver doesn't have this facility built in?

*Please see below for some fixes I've already attempted (without success), I'm looking forward to hearing your ideas! Let me know if I can help to provide any more information.*

---

Fixes attempted so far:

- **'Mapping feature' within device driver:** looking online, I see that many newer tablets (e.g., Wacom) have a built-in 'mapping' feature within their driver that allows you to set the tablet to only correspond to one (area) of your screens. Unfortunately the Kanvus 54 driver (I'm using the original from the CD) does not have this.
- **Dual Monitor Tools:** I followed the advice on this [previous thread](https://superuser.com/questions/749224/locking-a-wacom-graphics-tablet-to-one-screen-and-the-mouse-to-another-dual-mon) and downloaded Dual Monitor Tools to try to use its cursor locking function. Whilst the software successfully locked my regular mouse, it did not seem to work on the graphics tablet. The graphics tablet pointer remains able to freely move between both screens.
- **Cursor lock:** As with Dual Monitor Tools in 2 above, tried ["Cursor Lock" - a freeware solution](http://www.snakebytestudios.com/projects/apps/cursor-lock/) that claims to do the same thing. It produced the same results (regular mouse locked, graphics tablet not locked).

Comment: As I understand, you're trying to mirror the tablet with one of your screens.  Is this correct?

Comment: I think it might have to be in the tablet's control panel. As you say, Wacom has this facility; without it, it maps to 'everything'.

Comment: Hi Salocor, I'm hoping to configure it so that the graphics tablet maps to just my second screen. So, in an ideal world:
- top right of tablet maps to top right of second screen
- bottom left of tablet maps to bottom left of second screen
... but my regular mouse would remain able to access both screens as normal.
Let me know if I've not explained this clearly.